# In AWS-Lambda(Python), how can I Invoke External API which needs Token Authorization in the header

Tags: python, aws-lambda, authorization, token

I'm calling API in the AWS-Lambda(Python) function, but this external API needs a Token in the header. How should I configure/pass token in the header to my Lambda function?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I usually go for Python's `requests` module. It's not an included package in Lambda, so you'll need to package your function with the module included. Usually I need to include other modules, so little extra work. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Alternatively, you could use `urllib/urllib3` which is already included. https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

The documentation for both will explain how to set headers.